# Simple receiver unwanted selectivity

Tags: amplifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCsbNw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In an earlier question I asked help building a simple RF receiver/amplifier. Thanks to help from Andy aka I was able to build the circuit above.

I'm using a function generator and a long piece of wire to transmit. To the input of this receiver I've connected another piece of straight wire. I connect my oscilloscope between the negative terminal of the battery and the transistor collector.

I turn on my function generator, touch the positive lead to the long wire and I see a nice amplified sine wave on my oscilloscope (the function generator and this receiver are a few meters apart). I also tried connecting the output to a bridge rectifier and I was able to blink an LED nicely.

So everything works nicely except one thing: It only works with a frequency of around 3.8Mhz, even with no kind of tuning circuit! It's quite selective: at 3.7 or 4 MHz the output is almost nothing.

Then I tried to use the function generator directly as an input: Now the problem is gone. Any frequency is amplified and with the rectifier connected I can blink the LED.

The transmitter antenna is a piece of wire around 4-5 meters long hanging from the ceiling. The receiver antenna is another piece of wire, around 1 meter long. I've tried both building the circuit on a breadboard and soldering it to a perfboard. I've checked my setup many times, I don't think I've made any mistake in setting up this experiment. I've also tried a loop antenna (around 7 turns of cable around 30cm in diameter). It also has the same selectivity at 3.8Mhz.

So my question is: How is the circuit showing such unwanted selectivity? I've also tried tuning it with an LC circuit, but it simply attenuates the 3.8Mhz frequency as well. Another thing to mention is that the circuit at 3.8Mhz also works only when the oscilloscope negative lead is connected to the ground of this circuit (regardless whether the positive lead is connected or not).

EDIT: Here are pictures of my setup. This quality is the best I could do. Please excuse my poor editing skills. This circuit on the perfboard has the amplifier as in the schematic connected to a rectifier whose output is connected to the small breadboard and the LED. This setup works very well on 3.8 MHz.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is a transmitter.  Why does the title reference the receiver?

Comment: @JRE What makes you think it is a transmitter? In my experiment it functions as a BJT common emitter amplifier for the received signal.

Comment: A 100uF capacitor on an input usually means you expect have some low frequencies passing through.

Comment: @JRE Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The capacitor is there to block DC.  Together with the resistors it is connected to, it form a high pass filter.  The cutoff would be very low - like single digits low (10Hz or less.). For RF, I'd expect a cutoff below the lowest RF frequency you expect to receive.  Certainly I'd expect it to be at least above audio frequencies.

Comment: @JRE Some quick calculations place the cutoff of my circuit very low due to the relatively high capacitance. But my circuit does something else: It seems to instead block low frequencies, as well as higher ones.

Comment: Replace that 100uF with something smaller (nF range.) You may find that that helps with your problem.  If so, post back.

Comment: @JRE I tried 100nf, 10nf, 1nf and even a few values on the picofarad scale. Nothing worked, I either get correct behavior around 3.8Mhz or no output at all. But shouldn't I instead try larger values? Wouldn't larger values decrease the cutoff? I wasn't able to try larger ones since 100uf is the largest I have at the moment.

Comment: 100uF has you down below audio frequencies already.  Something else is the cause.  Could you post a picture of what you have built?

Comment: The OP is driving a simple wire hanging from a freq-gen. No indication even whether the 50 Ohm output is being used or something else (TTL, CMOS, gosh knows what.) The OP is then just hanging another wire a distance away and using it to drive what I believe (from prior posts) is just a 2N2222. Not an RF BJT. But a 2N2222 arranged in a CE amplifier arrangement without bootstrapping; instead of a common base for shielding and to prevent oscillation. This isn't after demod/detection/multiplication. This is straight off of an "antenna." I think. Am I getting this right?

Comment: @JRE I put some pictures into my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.8 MHz has a wavelength of 79 metres and you have a distance between your antennas of maybe 1 or 2 metres. This means that they do not act as EM transmitters but they act as plates of a capacitor to each other. So this is answering one of your questions: -

> Another thing to mention is that the circuit at 3.8Mhz also works only
>   when the oscilloscope negative lead is connected to the ground of this
>   circuit

You need a complete circuit to pass current capacitively and, earthing via your scope, connects your receiver to the earth on your oscillator through the AC wiring in your building.

And that brings in something else to consider - that AC wiring is a "system" in its own right and can offer all kinds of impedances at frequencies in the MHz range - who is to say that it isn't this wiring that is causing the series resonance at 3.8 MHz? If the wiring offered an inductance of 1 mH and the capacitance between your wires was 1 pF then this forms an effective resonant filter of 5.03 MHz. If your wiring offered 1.75 mH then your resonant frequency is 3.8 MHz!!!

So, in summary: -

- You are not transmitting EM waves between the two wires
- The gap being about 1 metre compared the wavelemgth being nearly 80 metres substantiates this.
- This means you are coupling capacitively
- Your coupling requires a return connection
- That return connection is through your AC wiring
- It could easily form a resonant filter with the capacitance between the two wires.

Try directly connecting the signal generator ground to your amplifier ground and see what happens. My money is on it being a gamechanger.

Comment: It was indeed a gamechanger. I simply connected the FG negative lead to the ground of the circuit and now it works across the frequencies. I'm still curious however, how exactly is it now working capacitively instead of EM waves? I mean, I understand that the distance is small compared to the wavelength but I'm still sending current to the transmitting wire, should this not still produce radiation regardless of how close the receiver is? Or is it both receiving waves and the capacitive connection and the former somehow dominates the effect? What if my frequency was much higher?

Comment: In the near field of a non-loop antenna you only receive the electric field therefore you only receive capacitive energy and this needs a full circuit i.e. A return path for current. A proper EM wave from an antenna requires at least a quarter wave monopole and this needs to be about 20 metres in length for your frequency so it neither meets the wavelength criteria nor are the two antennas sited at a sufficient distance such that a proper EM field is formed. You have a capacitive connection and this needs a return path.

Comment: The distance that a proper EM field is formed is about at one wavelength for a dipole or monopole. That's about 80 metres but it's no good moving your two circuits apart because the wires are not quarter wave tuned because they are much too short and the signal you would pick up at 80 metres would be too small to register with just a simple amplifier and o scope. Hey, nobody ever said rf was easy but I admire your experiment because it had me foxed for a while!

Comment: In the end this experiment turned out more interesting than I anticipated! Just out of curiosity I plugged the oscilloscope to another power outlet in another room, and now the working frequency is around 4.4 MHz. So apparently different paths through my house's electrical connections offer different inductances. I also replaced the wires with "plates" of tin foil, and it works even better. I can also eliminate the need for the earth by having another pair of "plates" as the return path. Anyway, thank you again for help!

Comment: Cool, glad to help out. But remember it is only using E fields and not proper radio waves.

Comment: Yes, I understand that now. But it makes no difference for my project, I just need it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have two effects that combine to give a peak in the response.

The antenna is physically short relative to the wavelength of the frequencies being received so it will act as a low value coupling capacitor between the transmitter and receiver - This will give a rising response @6db/octave.  The low input impedance of you circuit will tend to put the rollover point fairly high.

The amplifier itself will have a fairly low frequency response that will be falling at 6db/octave.  The main effect is probably caused by the 22k resistor and the base to collector capacitance.

The two effects combined will tend to give a peak at some frequency.

You don't say how selective it is - can you plot the response from say 1MHz to 10MHz?

Comment: Interesting, I simply did not give much thought to the length of the receiving antenna. Can you explain more about this phenomenon of the receiving antenna acting as a coupling capacitor when it's physically short? How would the situation change if it was longer?

Answer (score 0):

Assume the input wire is 1uH. Assume Cin (Cob * Av=60) is 1nF.

Fring is 31,000,000 radians per second or 5MHz.